# How to include only needed modules in pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using `pyinstaller` to generate an `.exe` file for my single python file, but the size is more than 30MB and the startup is very slow. From what I have gathered is that `pyinstaller` by default bundles a lot of stuff that are not needed. Is there a way to make sure that `pyinstaller` figures out what is only needed and bundles only them? My import section on my script looks like this:

```
import datetime
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import xlsxwriter
from tkinter import *
```

**EDIT:**

Or is there also a way to see the list of all modules it has bundled? So I can go through them and exclude the ones I don’t need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up using `cx_Freeze` in the end. It seems to work much better than `py2exe` or `pyinstaller`. I wrote `setup.py` file that looks like this:

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\bin\Python37-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\bin\Python37-32\tcl\tk8.6'

__version__ = '1.0.0'
base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

include_files = ['am.png']
includes = ['tkinter']
excludes = ['matplotlib', 'sqlite3']
packages = ['numpy', 'pandas', 'xlsxwriter']

setup(
    name='TestApp',
    description='Test App',
    version=__version__,
    executables=[Executable('test.py', base=base)],
    options = {'build_exe': {
        'packages': packages,
        'includes': includes,
        'include_files': include_files,
        'include_msvcr': True,
        'excludes': excludes,
    }},
)

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(__file__), os.pardir))
build_path = os.path.join(path, 'build', 'exe.win32-3.7')
shutil.copy(r'C:\bin\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll', build_path)
shutil.copy(r'C:\bin\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll', build_path)
```

Any then one can either run `python setup.py build_exe` to generate an executable or `python setup.py bdist_msi` to generate an installer.

Answer (score 16):

For this you need to create a separate environment, because currently you are reading all the modules you have installed on your computer.
To create environment run commands

1 - if you don't have one, create a `requirements.txt` file that holds all packages that you are using, you could create one with:

```sh
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

2 - create env folder:

```sh
python -m venv projectName
```

3 - activate the environment:

```sh
source projectName/bin/activate
```

4 - install them:

```sh
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

alternatively if you know you are using only wxpython you could just `pip install wxpython`

5 - then finally you can run `pyinstaller` on your main script with the `--path` arg as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645519/5133524):

```sh
pyinstaller --paths projectName/lib/python3.7/site-packages script.py
```

Comment: This still includes all modules in the base Python library.

Comment: Yes, this will only work if you don't have any adicional packages installed in /usr/lib/python.

Comment: I do unfortunately have packages installed in my base Python library. Is there a solution that will not include all those as well?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it can figure that out for you. If there are any specific modules taking a while to load, use the `--exclude-module` flag to list all the modules you want to exclude.

edit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890159/python-excluding-modules-pyinstaller/17595149#17595149) may have some more helpful info

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the most voted answer, you should install pyinstaller within your current virtual environment, and use --paths to select the right package directory. Otherwise, pyinstaller will still include all packages outside the virtual environment even though they are not used in your project at all.