# pyinstaller can't find custom imported modules

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to build executable using pyinstaller in mac os (python 3.7) , my file
parser.py is using some of my other files in the same directory , code includes import as below :

from logparser import parsingutility as parseUtil

pyintsaller builds the executables , running it shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named logparser.

I tried including directory path in --paths while building executable. Didn't work .

Comment: Worked after moving my parser.py out of my logparser directory and then providing path of logparser directory in --path arg of pyinstaller :)

Answer (score 0):

Create separate environment using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), and the rest is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312146/how-to-include-only-needed-modules-in-pyinstaller/55312484#55312484)

To create separate environment:

**1**. (in your project foler)

```
 $ python3 -m venv environment_name
```

this will create a folder environment_name in current directory.

**2**.

```
$ source project_name/bin/activate
```

to exit environment

`$ deactivate`

Comment: Thanks @lizardowl5151 , unfortunately this did't work. Still getting the same issue

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862192/16270364) is your situation, might help

Comment: Still no luck :(  bdw thanks @lizardowl5151