# How to set up Auto-Py-To-Exe so it looks at VENV for dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and I've looked at all the posts possible and cannot fix it...

I don't use PyCharm - I use VSCode
[How to include dependencies from venv directory when running pyinstaller for project built in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757977/how-to-include-dependencies-from-venv-directory-when-running-pyinstaller-for-pro)
I have also looked at various different online posts but nothing I try works and youtube videos.
[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=th77Z7XC1CY&ab_channel=CodewithShibu)

Here are the images of my entire inputs for `Auto-Py-To-Exe`. Would prefer it to be a single file but that doesn't work and just stops at building `PKG`...

In the `PATH` section I have specified my path to the `site-packages` but it still trying to look at the main path at `C:\\Main Storage\\_GitHub Repos\\Cued-Speech\\app\\eng_to_ipa\\resources`.

Please someone help me understand the reason this is happening and what I can do to solve it. Many Thanks in Advance.
[image][image]

**Error Log**

```
C:\Main Storage\_GitHub Repos\Cued-Speech\app>app.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
    import eng_to_ipa
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "eng_to_ipa\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "eng_to_ipa\transcribe.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "eng_to_ipa\stress.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "eng_to_ipa\syllables.py", line 13, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Main Storage\\_GitHub Repos\\Cued-Speech\\app\\eng_to_ipa\\resources\\phones.json'
[7100] Failed to execute script 'app' due to unhandled exception!
```

**Update**

All modules have `__init__.py`.

I need the app to look at this relative path when turned into exe `./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, its currently looking at
`C:\\Main Storage\\_GitHub Repos\\Cued-Speech\\app\\eng_to_ipa\\resources\\phones.json` which is my local path and inside the actual app folder it generated itself... instead of using the specified path with `--path` by auto-py-to-exe.

I have also tried giving `--path` a relative path but every single time the box kept turning red as soon as I remove `C:/`.

I have also realised that the python version used by the app is 3.8 not 3.10 so I changed my venv to match the version and that didn't change anything.