# Converting django app to windows exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

I converted a Django application into a Windows application using pyinstaller. I created a separate file runserver.py where I'm running the server in a thread and then opening the web browser using the web browser module. I'm getting an error as No Python at 'path'. It is taking my path on other computers too. It's not taking the path of env I created within Django

How can I activate the env of Django so that when people click on exe it should use the dependencies of env created within the Django app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757977/how-to-include-dependencies-from-venv-directory-when-running-pyinstaller-for-pro - looks like duplicate...