# pyInstaller bundle streamLit components

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, streamlit

I want to wrap a `streamlit==1.3.0` application into a single executable. This application uses extra components (`streamlit authenticator==0.3.0`). I am currently using `pyInstaller` to do so. I want to wrap the environment I work on so it has all the dependencies.

I've been looking through several questions on the topic [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645519/12881307). I've managed to build the application, but I get the following error when executing the resulting file:

```
File "extra_streamlit_components/TabBar/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
File "streamlit/components/v1/components.py", line 320, in declare_component
File "streamlit/components/v1/components.py", line 360, in register_component
streamlit.errors.StreamlitAPIException: No such component directory: '/tmp/_MEIHN61O8/extra_streamlit_components/TabBar/frontend/build'
```

where `TabBar/__init__.py` contains the following lines:

```py
    absolute_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    build_path = os.path.join(absolute_path, "frontend/build")
    _component_func = components.declare_component("tab_bar", path=build_path) # throws the above error
```

After looking inside the code in my `.venv` folder, I believe this must be caused by these components not being properly handled by `pyInstaller` (the `extra_streamlit_components/TabBar/frontend` folder is not a python directory, maybe `pyInstaller` does not bundle it as it thinks it is irrelevant?).

There are several streamlit components I need to use, none of which can be imported for the same reason.

I want to:

- find a way to add these folders to the `pyInstaller` executable
- have the environment created by `pyInstaller` resolve the components without problems

Answer (score 0):

try including the additional components and their frontend folders using the `--add-data flag` so it can bundle the folders into executable

if not try adjusting the paths to the frontend folders to match the bundled structure created by pyInstaller.

```
pyinstaller --add-data "path/to/additional/components:path/to/frontend/folder" your_app_file.py
```